# using jquery $.post() for returning multiple values

Tags: jquery, variables, .post

I am trying to use a $.post() in the following way:

`$.post("file.php", { file_id: $(this).val()}, function(data){...}`
The `file.php` then does a database query and returns an array with a title, description and image reference.

What I want to do then is be able to update the `.val()` for form fields for each. I understand how to do this on a single variable, it would just be the following:

```
$.post("file.php", { file_id: $(this).val()}, function(data){ 
   $('#title').val(data);
}
```

But, how do I get the data returned to be recognizable in jquery as either separate variables or as an array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the docs for $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The fourth parameter is the dataType. You can set this to JSON for your return data to be parsed into a JavaScript object or array.

```
$.post(
   "file.php", 
   { file_id: $(this).val() }, 
   function(data){ $('#title').val(data.title); $('#para').val(data.paragraph); },
   'json');
```

In your file.php file, you can do something like

```
<?php
$return_data=array('title'=>'Fishes Go To Market','paragraph'=>'Lots of stuff');

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
```

Be sure to include the header() so jQuery knows your data is supposed to be JSON, and to use json_encode so it is formatted properly.

See the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) docs for more info on that, and the [docs on header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Remeber you can't have any other output come before your header() and printing the json_encoded data, or the header as well as the JSON will be invalid.

Comment: worked perfectly, but I think you have a typo in your code ($return_data || $return_array)  Thanks!

Comment: Oops, that's right. I'll edit it for posterity. Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to pass back the values as JSON. You will need to convert your array to JSON on the server (there are lots of [server-side libraries available for this](http://www.json.org/)). And modify your `.post()` method to return the data as JSON by adding a fourth parameter like:

```
$.post("file.php", { file_id: $(this).val()}, function(data) { ... }, "json");
```

You can then populate your variables as easily as:

```
$('#title').val(data.title);
$('#description').val(data.description);
```